# change one element affects other element jquery css

Tags: jquery, css

i'm working on a little project while using jquery and css. i just finished a tutorial few days ago and i will be glad if you could help me with this subject.

i want to make an effect of zoom (by change height and width), but when i change the height 
all the elements underneath him in the page are jumping down(i want them to stay at their place without jumping).

the same is with the width, when i change the width, all the elements in the same line are moving.

```
.resume-menu .container div:hover{
height:40px;
opacity: 1;
background-color: lightblue;
}


.info .container .personal li:hover {
width:23%;
```

}

thanks for any help :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You could use [CSS3 transforms](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/transform):

```css
div:hover {
    -webkit-transform: scale(1.2);        
       -moz-transform: scale(1.2);
            transform: scale(1.2);
}
```

**[Example here](http://jsbin.com/rovema/2/edit)**

Comment: that work's great :) can you explain me those commands? or maybe you have a link that explain that? in codecademy there was no explanation about commands like this. thanks..

Answer (score 1):

> i want to make an effect of zoom

You can just use css.

This is an example:

```
div{
   -webkit-transform: scale(.9);
   -moz-transform: scale(.9);
   transform: scale(.9);
   zoom: .9;
}
```

**Edit:**

The zoom property in CSS allows you to scale your content. It is non-standard, and was originally implemented only in Internet Explorer. Although several other browsers now support zoom, it isn't recommended for production sites.

[see more about this](http://css-tricks.com/almanac/properties/z/zoom/)

Comment: If I remember correctly, `zoom` changes the size of the node (which affects the layout) but `scale` changes the view size of it.

Comment: zoom for ie only... other browsers doesn't recognise zoom